# OpenCart 3 SEO URLs not working correctly

Tags: php, opencart-3

Seems like it's not a rare issue, yet I couldn't find a proper solution for it.

My assumption is that since there is the SEO URLs core module it should do the work without any additional modules or .htaccess edits. But after I enable SEO URLs in System/Settings/Server not all of my URLs are SEO. Some of them change to SEO, but others still look like `index.php?route=account/register`, `index.php?route=information/contact`, `index.php?route=product/product&path=57&product_id=49` etc.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two methods to fix this problem in Opencart 3x.

**First Method**

1. Go to design/SEO URL
2. Click on Add new
3. In Query add account/register or information/contact or route path or product/category id.
4. Enter the Keyword (should be unique)
5. Select store and language and save it.

**Second Method**

Please Use anyone Free Extension from the following...

1. [SEO URL issue fix in Opencart 3.x By Sainent](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=31993&filter_search=seo&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55)
2. [Seo Friendly Urls](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=24846&filter_search=seo&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55)
3. [SEO_URL remove common/home,information/contact ... index.php](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=32424&filter_search=seo&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55&page=2)
4. [Opencart Seo All Links](https://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=marketplace/extension/info&extension_id=15773&filter_search=seo&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=55&page=2)

To remove the common/home you need to change the following files

Open seo_url.php from catalog/controller/startup.

find

```
} elseif ($key == 'path') {
```

and replace with

```
 } elseif ($key == 'route') {
 $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "seo_url WHERE `query` = '" . $this->db->escape($value) . "' AND store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' AND language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "'");
if ($query->num_rows && $query->row['keyword']) {
$url .= '/' . $query->row['keyword'];
unset($data[$key]);
} else if ($data['route'] == "common/home") { 
$url .= '/'; 
} 

} elseif ($key == 'path') {
```

Hope this Answer might Help you

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So if I don't want to use any additional modules I should change all the URLs manually? I mean I'm pretty new at OpenCart so I don't know at this point if it's just the core OC module SEO URL doesn't work out of the box as it's supposed to (change ALL the URLs to SEO like, say, Drupal's Pathauto, not just some of them) or is it something wrong with my setup?

Comment: @mikebrsv yes you have to change all the URLs Manually if you don't want to use any extension, but to remove common/home you have to change the code in the seo_url.php file( Updated in Answer). If the answer helped you please accept the answer.